# maven-release-plugin getting ride of the annoying plugin commits

Tags: git, maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

So, general question. I'm trying to get ride of the commits that maven-release-plugin makes automatically on my repo. so the

```
[maven-release-plugin] prepare for next development iteration
[maven-release-plugin] prepare release xxxx-32.95.104
```

My problem is that if at some point my release candidate goes to production i will branch from it to make further fixes, when my fixes are ready (which means that in I could have made several packages) i will want to merge back to development/master branch, but, off course, because of this commits it gets very hard, there are constants conflicts, etc.

So, I why for example the plugin doen't make itself a release branch everytime to run it, and will tag the commit on this branch where it sets the right verion numbers, but it never actually touch the pom files on the development/fix branch. When you merge back to master/development you have then exactly the same pom versions, so no conflicts. The version is just changed to correct when doing a mvn release, but in a different branch.

Is that possible?

Comment: If you want the release plugin to do its work on a release branch, why don't you check out a release branch before telling the release plugin to do its work?  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Those two commits will not cause your conflicts...The problem is the change in versions in your pom files...

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, the pom file is also located in the master/development branch, so, it doesn't mater if I make an special release branch, just for releasing, i will have conflicts when merging the fixes back to the development branch

Comment: @khmarbaise It will cause conflict if you have made few mvn releases on the development branch. Even more if you want to maintain the version numbers. So if we had release last week, 2.8, then development goes to 2.9, 2.10, after a week i need a patch to the release branch, so I make 2.8.1, if I merge back to development branch which is 2.8, i generally get conflicts. Maybe we are using just wrong git flow.

Comment: You might need to take a look at [Maven 3.5.0](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/release-notes.html) in particular the part http://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html